# How to find element in brackets

Tags: java, regex

I need the value in parentheses for the annotation in the text field. Example:

`String text = "I have simple annotation @Test(value123) and ..`

I can find the annotation itself with a value, but I don't understand how to get it without an annotation
`Pattern patternString = Pattern.compile("@Test\\(\\s+\\)");`

Result:

> @Test(value123)

but I need

> value123

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: you need to use look behind/ahead or groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `(X)` [capturing group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#logical):

```java
String text = "I have simple annotation @Test(value123) and ..";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("@Test\\(([^)]*)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // Print capture group 1
}
```

*Output*

```
value123
```

*Explanation*

```
@Test\(     Match '@Test('
(           Start of capturing group 1
  [^)]*       Match zero-or-more characters, except ')'
)           End of capturing group 1
\)          Match ')'
```

---

Alternatively, use `(?<=X)` [zero-width positive lookbehind](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special) and `(?=X)` [zero-width positive lookahead](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special):

```java
String text = "I have simple annotation @Test(value123) and ..";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=@Test\\()[^)]*(?=\\))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group()); // Print matched text
}
```

*Output*

```
value123
```

*Explanation*

```
(?<=          Start of zero-width positive lookbehind
  @Test\(       Match '@Test('
)             End of zero-width positive lookbehind
[^)]*         Match zero-or-more characters, except ')'
(?=           Start of zero-width positive lookahead
  \)            Match ')'
)             End of zero-width positive lookahead
```

Comment: Thank you, its working. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a matcher, like this:

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testString = "@Test(value123)";
    // unescaped parentheses catch the group
    // note that I changed \\s+ to .+,
    // since I want to match whatever is inside the parentheses,
    // not whitespaces (however, you should adjust it to your needs)
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@Test\\((.+)\\)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testString);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
      String value = matcher.group(1);
      System.out.println(value); // prints value123
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, its working. Good luck!

Comment: @MaximMaxim You should up-vote both answers if you found them useful.

Comment: @Andreas i can vote only for one answer. How to vote for both answers?

Comment: @MaximMaxim press the arrow indicating upwards, not the checkmark.

Comment: @Andreas 
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."